# Re-adding migration after delete migration file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, migration, package-managers

I have coded everything perfectly and created a migration file. It had everything I needed, but I accidentally deleted it.

I try to re-create it and it doesn't give me all the stuff I need, it just gives me a blank page with skeleton code.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the tooling believes/knows that the migration has been applied, that's why when you add a migration you're not getting an implemented up and down methods. If you don't have any sensitive data in your database you can deleted the database, and then run the command `Update-Database`. All the existing migrations will be checked and applied, and now you can know run `Add-Migration <MigrationName>`.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want this to happen anymore in the future, you can use [TFS](http://tfs.visualstudio.com/) for your source control or can use [File History](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/25799-file-history-restore-previous-file-versions-windows-8-a.html)

I think you can just delete the Migrations folder from your project. I will recreate again and uses the existing database.